# Any denumerable set is infinite

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Currently, I'm learning 'An Introduction to Classical Real Analysis' (Stromberg, 1981) by myself and find that the proof of Theorem (1.55) in pages 29-30 is far beyond my comprehension. Can anybody explain the statement below that g is onto N? 
I am looking forward your valuable help. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: There has always been some ambiguity with the term countable or denumerable. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set) tries to separate the notions clearly. For your question, can we know how $\mathbb{N}$ was defined in this book?

Comment: In this book, N is defined as the set of natural numbers [or the positive integers].

Answer (score 1):

Take $m\in\Bbb N$.

Suppose that $m<f(n)$. Since $f$ is onto, there is some $r$ such that $1\leq r\leq n$ and $f(r)=m$. And since $f$ is one to one, $r<n$. Then $g(r)$ is defined and $g(r)=m$.

If $m\geq f(n)$ then $m+1>f(n)$. Again, since $f$ is onto there exists some $r$ such that $f(r)=m+1$. And since $f$ is one to one, $r<n$. Then $g(r)$ is defined and $g(r)=f(r)-1=m$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No. Note that the domain of $f$ is $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, so $r>n$ does not make sense.

Comment: Since the domain of g is {1,…,n-1}, I wonder why the range of g is the same as that of f.